# HSQLDB with Hibernate not saving records after application end

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have a sample application which loads 2 records ro database and then fetches all the records from DB and prints info from every record.

My problem is follow: when I run program, it fetches only records which inserted on this running, but not before, Also, when I'm opening DB with SQirrel, there is no such database.

Here is my Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hibertest</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sk</property>
        <property name="connection.password">0000</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="models.Work" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not experienced with HSQLDB but try the following URL:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:hibertest;shutdown=true</property>
```

See: [*Connection URL* documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_connection_url).

Comment: This is an alternative form of the same URL (a file database). See this for additional properties to use on the URL.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238399/clojure-jdbc-create-table-statement-does-not-run-unless-using-leiningen-repl

Comment: @Tomasz please add the extra properties that are required for persistence to your answer. See the link I posted.

Comment: @fredt: feel free to edit my answer, please. You have enough repo to do this. Or create another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default configuration of hsqldb is to not save data on disk for created tables.  Please check the hsqldb documentation for how to change this behavior and make tables persistent.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#sgc_persist_tables

Answer (score 1):

All the provided answers didn't help me at all.
Currently I use HSQLDB-2.3.2 and hibernate-core-3.5.6 with annotations-3.2.0

In addition to the answer of Tomasz, I needed to manually edit the database script file setting this:

```
SET WRITE_DELAY 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can persist the Data using the HSQL by doing the following,
1.

```
 Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/opt/db/testdb", "SA", "");
```

**"/opt/db/testdb" here is the DB location in the disk.**

2. `CREATE **TEXT** TABLE <tablename> (<column definition> [<constraint definition>])`
3. Assign the source for the Table
 `SET TABLE mytable SOURCE "myfile;fs=|"`

Ref: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html

My Github Repository shows the sample https://github.com/Ayyamperumal/HSQL/tree/master/SampleHSQLdb

you can use "Database Development" perspective from Eclipse to see the data. (Supply hsql jar as the driver)  Or Execute **org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager** from the hsqldb-*.jar to get the GUI for seeing the data.