# Database mocking in Clojure tests

Tags: postgresql, testing, clojure, mocking, korma

How can I mock my postgres database for testing?

My application is very simple, but I cannot find a good way to mock my database for tests. In Java I usualy use HSQLDB, but there is a solution in Clojure?

This is my project file.

```
  (defproject account-manager "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
            :description "Account Manager"
            :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
            :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
                      :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
            :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                           [compojure "1.5.2"]
                           [cheshire "5.7.0"]
                           [ring/ring-core "1.5.1"]
                           [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                           [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.5.1"]
                           [korma "0.4.3"]
                           [org.clojars.amit/postgresql "8.0.1"]
                           [com.h2database/h2 "1.4.188"]
                           [ragtime "0.7.1"]
                           [environ "1.1.0"]
                           [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                           [buddy/buddy-hashers "1.2.0"]
                           [clj-time "0.13.0"]]
            :plugins [[lein-ring "0.11.0"]]

            :ring {:handler account-manager.handler/app
                   :nrepl {:start? true
                           :port 9998}}

            :profiles
            {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                                  [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]
                   :env {:bank-db "bank_db"
                         :bank-db-user "bank_db"
                         :bank-db-pass "-"}}
             :test {:env {:bank-db "bank_db"
                          :bank-db-user "bank_db"
                          :bank-db-pass "-"}}})
```

And this is how I'm configuring my database. In the future I will use configuration files.

```
(ns bank-account-manager.db
  (:use korma.db)
  (:require [environ.core :refer [env]]))

(defdb db (postgres {:db (get env :bank-db "bank_db")
                     :user (get env :bank-db-user "bank_db")
                     :password (get env :bank-db-pass "-")
                     :host (get env :bank-db-host "localhost")
                     :port (get env :bank-db-port 5432)}))
```

There is a good way to mock?

Comment: Have you tried to use HSQLDB?

Comment: I did not find any reference of someone using HSQLDB. You have an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238399/clojure-jdbc-create-table-statement-does-not-run-unless-using-leiningen-repl

Comment: I would consider a different approach by use of function mocking.  The midge framework has many facilities for this:  https://github.com/marick/Midje

Comment: don't using different db in prod and in tests. look for db integration tests in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB works with clojure.java.jdbc.

[The readme](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc) there mentions that Korma is a compatible library with clojure.java.jdbc.

I don't see any reason why you can't continue to use HSQLDB as you would in Java then.

Comment: Is there any example how to configure the tests with it?

Comment: I don't see an example after a quick search. Can you provide an example of what you want the test to look like in your question?

Comment: I'm following this architecture https://kendru.github.io/restful-clojure/2014/02/16/writing-a-restful-web-service-in-clojure-part-1-setup/ . But I don't wanna to use vagrant, just docker for development and in memory db for tests.